# How to switch a user per task or set of tasks?

Tags: ansible

A recurring theme that's in my ansible playbooks is that I often must execute a command with sudo privileges (`sudo: yes`) because I'd like to do it for a certain user. Ideally I'd much rather use sudo to switch to that user and execute the commands normally. Because then I won't have to do my usual post commands clean up such as chowning directories. Here's a snippet from one of my playbooks:

```yaml
- name: checkout repo
  git: repo=https://github.com/some/repo.git version=master dest={{ dst }}
  sudo: yes
- name: change perms
  file: dest={{ dst }} state=directory mode=0755 owner=some_user
  sudo: yes
```

Ideally I could run commands or sets of commands as a different user even if it requires sudo to su to that user.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

#### With Ansible 1.9 or later

Ansible uses the `become`, `become_user`, and `become_method` directives to achieve privilege escalation. You can apply them to an entire play or playbook, set them in an included playbook, or set them for a particular task.

```
- name: checkout repo
  git: repo=https://github.com/some/repo.git version=master dest={{ dst }}
  become: yes
  become_user: some_user
```

You can use `become_with` to specify how the privilege escalation is achieved, the default being `sudo`.

The directive is in effect for the scope of the block in which it is used ([examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207067/807730)).

See [Hosts and Users](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#hosts-and-users) for some additional examples and [Become (Privilege Escalation)](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) for more detailed documentation.

In addition to the task-scoped `become` and `become_user` directives, Ansible 1.9 added some new variables and command line options to set these values for the duration of a play in the absence of explicit directives:

- [Command line options](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#command-line-options) for the equivalent `become`/`become_user` directives.
- [Connection specific variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#connection-variables) which can be set per host or group.

As of Ansible 2.0.2.0, the older `sudo`/`sudo_user` syntax described below still works, but the deprecation notice states, "This feature will be removed in a future release."

---

#### Previous syntax, deprecated as of Ansible 1.9 and scheduled for removal:

```
- name: checkout repo
  git: repo=https://github.com/some/repo.git version=master dest={{ dst }}
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: some_user
```

Comment: To specify the sudo_user from a variable, use quotes around your variable template, like this - `sudo_user: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"` or you would get a yaml syntax error.

Comment: Good catch. I was trying to match the OP's formulation of the problem as closely as possible, but I agree that using variable interpolation will be the most common choice.

Comment: From Ansible 1.9, it's the [`become` system](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) instead of "sudo*".

Comment: 1.9+ syntax for "become" is right. You may also want to check "become_method", as "su" could be sometimes better than default "sudo", depending on your system setup.

Comment: `New Ansible variables and command line options are added to set these values for the duration of a play. `  @Brett so does that mean the succeeding tasks after this will be ran by `some_user` and not the original user `remote_user` which was used to connect to the host, is that correct?

Comment: @JohnnyQ if you use the command line options, I would certainly expect them to be effective for each task in the play, assuming no contrary directives inside the playbook itself. However the documentation doesn't explicitly say this and I have not had occasion to verify this assumption. Remember you have to set **both** `become` and `become_user` for escalation to happen (via directive or the equivalent command line argument).

Comment: @Brett Tried it [here](https://gist.github.com/janzenz/8030b104c109df3b59f26d133c8af03b) Turns out that the user escalation goes back to the original user which you used to connect to as shown in my example.

Comment: `become_with` seems to have become `become_method`, https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#using-become

Answer (score 51):

In Ansible 2.x, you can use the `block` for group of tasks:

```
- block:
    - name: checkout repo
      git:
        repo: https://github.com/some/repo.git
        version: master
        dest: "{{ dst }}"
    - name: change perms
      file:
      dest: "{{ dst }}"
      state: directory
      mode: 0755
      owner: some_user
  become: yes
  become_user: some user
```

Answer (score 29):

In Ansible >1.4 you can actually specify a remote user at the task level which should allow you to login as that user and execute that command without resorting to sudo. If you can't login as that user then the sudo_user solution will work too.

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: test connection
      ping:
      remote_user: yourname
```

See http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html#hosts-and-users

Comment: This is the best solution for situations when you don't have sudo privileges

Answer (score 7):

A solution is to use the `include` statement with `remote_user` var (describe there : http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html) but it has to be done at playbook instead of task level.

Comment: This isn't a good solution for the use case above. However I wasn't aware of this solution for a long time. I thought I can only include roles.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `become_method` to override the default method set in `ansible.cfg` (if any), and which can be set to one of `sudo, su, pbrun, pfexec, doas, dzdo, ksu`.

```
- name: I am confused
  command: 'whoami'
  become: true
  become_method: su
  become_user: some_user
  register: myidentity

- name: my secret identity
  debug:
    msg: '{{ myidentity.stdout }}'
```

Should display

```
TASK [my-task : my secret identity] ************************************************************
ok: [my_ansible_server] => {
    "msg": "some_user"
}
```