# Installing Apache through Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am attempting to install Apache on an EC2 instance through Ansible. My playbook looks like this:

```
# Configure and deploy Apache
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  remote_user: ec2-user
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - ec2_apache
    - apache
```

The 'ec2_apache' role provisions an EC2 instance and the first task within the apache/main.yml looks like this:

```
- name: confirm using the latest Apache server
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  yum: 
    name: httpd 
    state: latest
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
"module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n"
```

I did take a look at: [How to switch a user per task or set of tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344777/how-to-switch-a-user-per-task-or-set-of-tasks/22749788#22749788) but it did not seem to resolve my problem.

Because the configuration of the Ec2 instance is in one role and the installation of Apache is in another, did I hork up the security in some way?

Comment: Do you need a password when you use `sudo` when you are on the instance as the `ec2-user`?

Comment: No, if I ssh into the newly created instance, I can do a basic 'sudo ls /etc' That is what has me stumped.  All of the example I have found online and through StackOverflow don't address creating an EC2 and THEN installing some piece of software or least within separate roles.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you've got is that your playbook that runs both roles is targeting `localhost` so your Apache role is trying to run `sudo yum install httpd` locally rather than on the target EC2 instance.

As the [ec2 module docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html) example shows you need to use the [add_host](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html) module to add your new EC2 instance(s) to a group that you can then target with a further play.

So your playbook might look something like this:

```
# Configure and deploy Apache
- name: provision instance for Apache
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  remote_user: ec2-user
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - ec2_apache

- name: install Apache
  hosts: launched
  remote_user: ec2-user
  roles:
    - apache
```

And then, as per the example in the ec2 module docs, just do something like this in your `ec2_apache` role:

```
- name: Launch instance
  ec2:
     key_name: "{{ keypair }}"
     group: "{{ security_group }}"
     instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
     image: "{{ image }}"
     wait: true
     region: "{{ region }}"
     vpc_subnet_id: subnet-29e63245
     assign_public_ip: yes
  register: ec2

- name: Add new instance to host group
  add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groupname=launched
  with_items: ec2.instances

- name: Wait for SSH to come up
  wait_for: host={{ item.public_dns_name }} port=22 delay=60 timeout=320 state=started
  with_items: ec2.instances
```

As an aside you can see quickly that your `ec2_apache` role is actually pretty generic and you could turn this into a generic `ec2_provision` role that all sorts of other things could use, helping you re-use your code.

Comment: I gave that a shot but there was no joy.  In both cases, I see the following: fatal: [xxx.xxx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false} where 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx' is the EC2 instance I am attempting to communicate with.  Does this mean Ansible is working against the correct EC2 host?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to install apache.
Based on @ydaetskcoR suggestion, all I added was connection: local to fix the following problems.

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive).", "unreachable": true}
```

See code below

```
---
- name: Install Apache and other packages
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: Install a list of packages with a list variable
    yum:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: latest
    vars:
      packages:
      - httpd
      - httpd-tools
      - nginx
    register: result
```

you also have to run your code as follows: `-K` stands for `--ask-become-pass`

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini startapache.yml -K -vvv
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using ansible correctly and are you provindig a password for sudo on the remote host?

Just use --ask-become-pass when you execute the playbook. You should  be prompted for the password.