# Ansible delegate_to how to set user that is used to connect to target?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an Ansible (2.1.1.) inventory:

```
build_machine ansible_host=localhost ansible_connection=local
staging_machine ansible_host=my.staging.host ansible_user=stager
```

I'm using SSH without `ControlMaster`.

I have a playbook that has a synchronize command:

```
- name: Copy build to staging
  hosts: staging_machine
  tasks:
    - synchronize: src=... dest=...
      delegate_to: staging_machine
      remote_user: stager
```

The command prompts for password of the wrong user:

`local-mac-user@my-staging-host's password:`

So instead of using `ansible_user` defined in the inventory or `remote_user` defined in task to connect to target (hosts specified in play), it uses the user that we connected to `delegate-to` box as, to connect to target hosts.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

EDIT: It works in 2.0.2, doesn't work in 2.1.x

Answer (score 3):

The `remote_user` setting is used at the playbook level to set a particular play run as a user.

example:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
  - name: ensure apache is at the latest version
    yum:
      name: httpd
      state: latest
  - name: write the apache config file
    template:
      src: /srv/httpd.j2
      dest: /etc/httpd.conf
```

If you only have a certain task that needs to be run as a different user you can use the  `become` and `become_user` settings.

```
- name: Run command
  command: whoami
  become: yes
  become_user: some_user
```

Finally if you have a group of tasks to run as a user in a play you can group them with `block`

example:

```
- block:
    - name: checkout repo
      git:
        repo: https://github.com/some/repo.git
        version: master
        dest: "{{ dst }}"
    - name: change perms
      file:
      dest: "{{ dst }}"
      state: directory
      mode: 0755
      owner: some_user
  become: yes
  become_user: some user
```

Reference: 
- [How to switch a user per task or set of tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344777/how-to-switch-a-user-per-task-or-set-of-tasks)
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html

Answer (score 0):

The one which works for me but please note that it is for Windows and Linux do not require `become_method: runas` and basically does not have it

```
- name: restart IIS services
  win_service:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    state: restarted
    start_mode: auto
    force_dependent_services: true
  loop:
    - 'SMTPSVC'
    - 'IISADMIN'
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
  become_user: '{{ webserver_user }}'
  vars:
    ansible_become_password: '{{ webserver_password }}'
  delegate_facts: true
  delegate_to: '{{ groups["webserver"][0] }}'
  when: dev_env
```

Answer (score -1):

Try set become: yes and become_user: stager on your YAML file... That should fix it...

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/become.html