# become_user auto detect ansible

Tags: ansible

I'd like to run a wine command using a non privileged user account so it creates it in their wine folder.  Is there a way become_user will auto detect the user that is running the ansible playbook?

For example, if I run the playbook and I install everything I need as a privileged user but I want to drop down to my own user account, is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch a user per task or set of tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344777/how-to-switch-a-user-per-task-or-set-of-tasks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `become: false` on the task you want to run as the user executing the playbook (assuming you have already set `become: true` for the entire play)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't use become: true in the code but I will do that, I just wanted to make sure user running the play would be used.